# Python import hooks: no filenames in trackback of import errors

Tags: python, import, trackback, import-hooks

I've written an import hook according to [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) and it seems to work fine except one annoying detail.
When there's an import error, say code that tries to import a module that doesn't exist, I get a trackback with lines like:

```
File "<string>", line 10, in helloEnv
```

line 10 is where the call to the non-existing import resides but there is no file name, just `<string>`.
My import hooks looks pretty much like the minimal one in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/). In the creation of the module I always set a proper string value to `__file__` and even check that `new_module()` sets a correct value to `__name__`. Also, both `str()` and `repr()` of the module return something informative.

These nameless files in the trackback makes it hard to debug import errors. Where does the trackback take its filenames from? why doesn't it see the names of the modules?

---

EDIT -  thinking about it some more, it's probably since the module code is executed using `exec()`. is it possible to give `exec()` a filename?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that was simple enough. instead of

```
exec(code, mod.__dict__)
```

write:

```
exec(compile(code, fullname, "exec"), mod.__dict__)
```